# Template name suggestion for multivalue image field in paragraph module?

Tags: theming, 8, entities, media, paragraphs

How can I create a dedicated template name suggestion for paragraphs multi value image field?

The below HTML comments are the theme hook suggestions added by the debug function, for the paragraph multi value image field.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->
```

As you can see from the template name suggestions, there is nothing to distinguish this intended image field from others.